# Should react-native apps target a specific version or subset of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, version, ecmascript-5

I'm working on my first React Native project and things are mostly working.

But on my new Xiaomi Android phone I got a crash when trying to use `String.fromCodePoint()`. It works fine on the iOS simulator.

In fact I'm not even sure which JavaScript engine is running the app on each device. I suppose each OS has one for their respective native browser.

I haven't been able to find any discussions on the Internet about what flavour of JavaScript I should use in my app for it to work on most devices.

Do I actually have to test for all features? Is there an official subset? Can I query the JS version in use from my app? What does everybody else do?

Answer (score 0):

[I found the answers on the React Native Site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html):

- The React Native people suggest using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).
- On Android the app will be using v8.
- On iOS the app will be using [JavaScriptCore (JSC)](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore).